Tomatoes measured in quarts
I have a recipe that calls for 8 quarts of tomatoes. How do you measure tomatoes by quart since it is a liquid measurement? Since the recipe uses a food processor, do you continue to process the tomatoes until you have 8 quarts?

Can you share the recipe with us, please?

how exactly is it worded?  "eight quarts diced tomatoes" means you dice first, then measure while "eight quarts of tomatoes, diced" means measure first then dice them

Tomatoes are mostly water (they're only slightly denser), so 16 pounds might be a reasonable starting point. Maybe add an extra one to account for some waste.

A quart is a liquid measure when it's, say, milk, but it's also a unit used in baskets of peaches, tomatoes, etc. 6 quart baskets are canonical, but 4 quart baskets do exist and this recipe doubtless wants two of those.
Given the varying sizes of tomatoes and how tightly they might be packed, this is never going to be a very accurate measure. Buy two 6 quart baskets of tomatoes (or get an old six quart basket from wherever you save them, we all save them) and use it to measure one basket plus -- very roughly -- a third of a basket. You know, a little less than half. It will be fine.

“8 quarts” specifically makes me think the recipe is a modernized version of an older recipe calling for a peck of tomatoes.

I cannot agree with this answer as it's pretty speculative given the lack of a recipe. It could be right, or not.

@GdD It’s possible the recipe called for puréed tomatoes and the OP didn’t bother mentioning it, or that the recipe was written incorrectly. But for a recipe that simply asked for “eight quarts of tomatoes”, this is absolutely the most likelyinterpretation.

@Sneftel That, or it could be talking about canned tomatoes. The norm for home-canning of vegetables, at least where I’m from, is 1-quart jars, which would mean the recipe is calling for eight jars, and I have seen soup recipes that actually do this. Either way, we really need more info about the recipe to make an accurate judgement.
